# Remote graphical access to Ubuntu 15.04 on raspberry pi 2 from outside network

Tags: networking, 15.04, remote, raspberrypi

I have Windows 7 and I would like to remotely access my rapsberry pi 2 running Ubuntu 15.04. I want remotely connect to its graphical interface and I cannot forward ports as I have no access to the router. How can I connect to it?